# insert function Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

So Basically i have made insert function in my BST

```
    @Override
    public TreeElement<T> insert(T value, Comparator<T> comp) {
        if(value == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("null not supported");

        int comparator = comp.compare(value, info);
        //iseti uazro bagebi mepareba auaa
        if(comparator > 0){
            if(right == null)
                return new InnerNode<>(value, new Leaf<>(value), left);
            else {
                return right = right.insert(value, comp);
            }
        }else if(comparator < 0){
            if(left == null)
                return new InnerNode<>(value, right, new Leaf<>(value));
            else {
                return left = left.insert(value, comp);
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
```

but there are some test cases it didn't get through and i can't even really comprehend them
first one:
The return type of the expected method 'insert' of the class 'InnerNode' with the parameters: ["Object","Comparator"] is not implemented as expected.

second one:
The parameters of the expected constructor of the class 'InnerNode' with the parameters: ["Object"] are not implemented as expected.

can you help me out?

as stated above i tried that code but it didn't run

Comment: There's a lot missing here. What are the types of `left` and `right`? What is the relationship between the `InnerNode` and `TreeElement` types?

Comment: i can upload the files on github if that might help. left and right are both TreeElement types and innerNode and leaf implement treeElement